# Remove jquery slider bar outer border

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Im trying to remove the outer border of the bar and cant seem to figure it out no matter what.  Ive looked a the others on what to do and ive tried.  Here is my [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/adviner/pw5nj/1/)

[image]

```
<div id="vertical-slider"></div>

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {

margin-left: .2em;
cursor: hande;

position: absolute;
height: 1.em;
width: 1.em;
z-index: 2;

outline: 0px;
outline: none; 
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle:focus { outline: none; }
.ui-slider-handle { outline: none; }
```

I know this is probably one of those "damn was that all it took" solutions :D

Comment: Did you try border:none?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#vertical-slider {
    border:0;
}
```

Worked for me

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fBeGA/)**

Comment: yup it was that.  The problem was i had a css somewhere else thats why it was driving me crazy.  Thanks a bunch for my duh :D

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
#vertical-slider.ui-slider {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pw5nj/3/